# Как сделать фрейм маленького размера, овальным?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qlayout

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

На первой картинке слева меню маленькое и полукруглое, а на второй картинке (на моей) при дальнейшем уменьшении теряется овальность и `frame` превращается в квадрат, как это исправить?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Apex.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QIcon 
from PyQt5.uic import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.menuvisible = 0
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1209, 747)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 161, 591))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.weapon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 121, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);      \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.weapon.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.weapon.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        self.spravka = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.spravka.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 540, 111, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.spravka.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.spravka.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.spravka.setFont(font)
        self.spravka.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"\n"
"    }\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.spravka.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.spravka.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.spravka.setObjectName("spravka")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 540, 61, 41))
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Nikita_Pfeyfer4.png"))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-30, 100, 81, 41))
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Nikita_Pfeyfer2.png"))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.menu.clicked.connect(self.showmenu) 
        self.menu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 51, 51))

        self.menu.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/menu/Изображения/back.png);\n"
"border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"")
        self.menu.setText("")
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1211, 21))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(253, 253, 253);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 130, 241, 2))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 180, 261, 161))
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(194, 194, 194);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 121, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 170, 256, 351))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 720, 201, 20))
        self.frame_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_4)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, -2, 101, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 360, 261, 161))
        self.textBrowser_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(309, 391, 161, 2))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(331, 219, 121, 2))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(870, 170, 256, 351))
        self.textBrowser_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #6c6c00;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(897, 200, 201, 2))
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        self.frame_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -1, 161, 170))
        self.frame_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);")
        self.frame_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_5.setObjectName("frame_5")
        self.mainmenu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_5)
        self.mainmenu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 161, 161))
        self.mainmenu.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/Fone/Изображения/_Logotip_Proz3.png); \n"
"border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"")
        self.mainmenu.setText("")
        self.mainmenu.setObjectName("mainmenu")
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.line.raise_()
        self.frame_3.raise_()
        self.textBrowser.raise_()
        self.frame_4.raise_()
        self.textBrowser_2.raise_()
        self.line_2.raise_()
        self.line_3.raise_()
        self.textBrowser_3.raise_()
        self.line_4.raise_()
        self.frame_5.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapons"))
        self.spravka.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reference"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Menu"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Версия"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1.0 BETA"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Эта программа предназначена для того, чтобы помочь новичкам или опытным игрокам более лучше освоить игру</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">_Apex Legends_</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Тут ты найдёшь подробное описание каждого оружия,</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; text-decoration: underline;\"> </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">обвеса и прочих вещей.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">С уважением, Разработчик </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Всё для вас!"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">Информация</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Программа находится в разработке, поэтому, пока что присудствует не вся информация </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">Кому принадлежит</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Все данные, изображения и прочее из программы, принадлежат компании</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\"> </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#6f6f0a;\">Respawn Entertainment</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Никому более.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Их материал был повзаимствован для помощи игрокам.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "справка"))

    def showmenu(self):
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b'size')
        self.anim.setDuration(250)
        if self.menuvisible==0:
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(50,751))
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(161, 751))
            self.menuvisible = 1
        else:
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(161,751))
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(50, 751))
            self.menuvisible = 0
            #self.anim.finished.connect(self.hidemenu)
        self.frame.show()
        self.anim.start()

import ApexFone
import menu

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше большая недоработка в том что вы не используете менеджеры компоновки и я не вижу всего окна вашего приложения.

Я изменил размеры и цвета стилей некоторых виджетов, чтобы картины мне была понятнее и вам будет нагляднее видно как виджеты расположены в окне у меня.

Из того что я понял, вы вы хотите поменять вид объекта `self.frame`. Смотрите стили для этого объекта. Обратите внимание на `border-radius` и другие изменения, которые я отметил в коде.

Изображения, которые я использовал - прикрепляю. Попробуйте сразу с ними, а потом переходите к своим картинкам.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
# ??? from PyQt5.uic import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.menuvisible = 0
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
#                               747
        MainWindow.resize(1209, 690)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("")
        MainWindow.setAnimated(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
# frame !!!
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
#        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 161, 591))
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 185, 161, 495))            # +
# +        
        self.frame.setStyleSheet('''
            .QFrame {
/*          ^ это точка, чтобы стили распространялись только на self.frame */
                background-color: #035397;
                border: 2px solid #FFAA4C;
                border-radius: 25px;                 /* <---- border-radius */
            }
        ''')
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        
        self.weapon = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.weapon.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 100, 121, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.weapon.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.weapon.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.weapon.setFont(font)
        self.weapon.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);      \n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.weapon.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.weapon.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.weapon.setObjectName("weapon")
        
        self.spravka = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.spravka.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 540, 111, 41))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.spravka.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.spravka.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.spravka.setFont(font)
        self.spravka.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    ;\n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(78, 75, 94);\n"
"    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"
"    padding: 5px;\n"
"\n"
"    }\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"   \n"
"    \n"
"    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);\n"
"    }\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: inset;\n"
"   \n"
"    color: rgb(214, 214, 214);\n"
"    }")
        self.spravka.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhNone)
        self.spravka.setAutoExclusive(False)
        self.spravka.setObjectName("spravka")
        
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 440, 61, 41))
        self.label_10.setText("")
        self.label_10.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"))
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 100, 41, 41))
        self.label_9.setText("")
        self.label_9.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ball.png"))
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")

# menu !!!       
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.menu.clicked.connect(self.showmenu) 
        self.menu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 51, 51))

        self.menu.setStyleSheet(
# --- "background-image: url(ball.png);\n"
# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
"border-image: url(Ok.png);"                                           # +++
 
# ??? "border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);\n"

"background-color: #035397;"                                           # +++
"")
        self.menu.setText("")
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1211, 21))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 243, 63);")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 90, 231, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Copperplate Gothic Bold")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(253, 253, 253);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 130, 241, 2))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 180, 261, 161))
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 0, 121, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(194, 194, 194);")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 60, 121, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 170, 256, 351))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 720, 201, 20))
        self.frame_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_4)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, -2, 101, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 360, 261, 161))
        self.textBrowser_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #2e2b3f;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(309, 391, 161, 2))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(331, 219, 121, 2))
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        
        self.textBrowser_3 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(870, 170, 256, 351))
        self.textBrowser_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);\n"
"border: 2px solid #6c6c00;\n"
"border-radius: 10")
        self.textBrowser_3.setObjectName("textBrowser_3")
        
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(897, 200, 201, 2))
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")

# !!!
        self.frame_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
#        self.frame_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, -1, 161, 170)) 
        self.frame_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 22, 161, 161))
        self.frame_5.setStyleSheet(
#            "background-color: rgb(46, 43, 63);"
            "background-color: #FF4C29;"              
        )
        self.frame_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_5.setObjectName("frame_5")
        
# !!!        
        self.mainmenu = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_5)
        self.mainmenu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 161, 161))
        
        self.mainmenu.setStyleSheet(
# "background-image: url(:/Fone/Изображения/_Logotip_Proz3.png); \n"

"border-image: url(Ok.png);"                                        # +++
"background-color: rgb(34, 31, 46);"                                # +++

# ??? "border: 3px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 222);\n"
"")
        self.mainmenu.setText("")
        self.mainmenu.setObjectName("mainmenu")
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        self.frame.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.line.raise_()
        self.frame_3.raise_()
        self.textBrowser.raise_()
        self.frame_4.raise_()
        self.textBrowser_2.raise_()
        self.line_2.raise_()
        self.line_3.raise_()
        self.textBrowser_3.raise_()
        self.line_4.raise_()
        self.frame_5.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.weapon.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Weapons"))
        self.spravka.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Reference"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Main Menu"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Версия"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1.0 BETA"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Эта программа предназначена для того, чтобы помочь новичкам или опытным игрокам более лучше освоить игру</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">_Apex Legends_</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Тут ты найдёшь подробное описание каждого оружия,</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; text-decoration: underline;\"> </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">обвеса и прочих вещей.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">С уважением, Разработчик </span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; color:#c2c2c2;\">ApexHelper</span><span style=\" font-size:12pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:12pt;\"><br /></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Всё для вас!"))
        self.textBrowser_2.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; font-weight:600; color:#c2c2c2;\">Информация</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Программа находится в разработке, поэтому, пока что присудствует не вся информация </span></p></body></html>"))
        self.textBrowser_3.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt; color:#c2c2c2;\">Кому принадлежит</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:16pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\">Все данные, изображения и прочее из программы, принадлежат компании</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:16pt;\"> </span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600; color:#6f6f0a;\">Respawn Entertainment</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Никому более.</span></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\"-qt-paragraph-type:empty; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px; font-size:14pt;\"><br /></p>\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt;\">Их материал был повзаимствован для помощи игрокам.</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "справка"))

    def showmenu(self):
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.frame, b'size')
        self.anim.setDuration(250)
        if self.menuvisible==0:
# !!!                                         751 -> self.frame.height()        
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(50, self.frame.height()))    
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(161, self.frame.height()))
            self.menuvisible = 1
        else:
            self.anim.setStartValue(QSize(161,self.frame.height()))
            self.anim.setEndValue(QSize(50, self.frame.height()))
            self.menuvisible = 0
            #self.anim.finished.connect(self.hidemenu)
        self.frame.show()
        self.anim.start()

# ??? import ApexFone
# ??? import menu


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ok.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ball.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я хочу поменять размеры Frame, я сделал этот Frame овальным, но когда я меняю размер этого фрэйма по ширине, то эта " Овальность" пропадает и он становится квадратным. Почему не понятно, но я это делаю через qt desinger. Не могли бы вы сказать, что такое менеджеры компоновки?

Comment: Что ниже, вы не видите, потому что я меняю размеры окна через main файл. Я посмотрел ваш файл, Frame сворачивается при нажатии на кнопку, но он изначально должен быть такой узкий и начинать расширяться при нажатии, но если его делать таким узким через qt designer, то он теряет овальность

Comment: забейте в гугле "qt компоновка виджетов". это позволит задать изменение размеров, коэффициетов растяжения и прочего при изменении размера окна. у вас размеры окон/виджетов заданы постоянными и это проблема для разных разрешений экрана. такое пожалуй имеет смысл только для небольших окон или в embeded разработке

Comment: @Sergey Tatarincev Я понял, про что вы. Но ведь мне полностью придётся переделывать программу. Да и я когда пытался сделать динамику, все файлы растягиваются по лайауту, поместить объект куда я хочу не получается. Если выбирать лайаут блоками, то объекты можно поместить друг за другом, при этом если поместить картинку, а слева от неё другую, то её размер сожмётся... и как с этим работать?

Comment: почитайте/посмотрите. это реально полезно. в частности обратите внимание на задание sizepolicy.

Comment: А разве использую компановку, объекты можно расположить как я хочу?

Comment: @НикитаПфейфер да, все можно. Я бы сказал, что не только можно, а нужно. Читаем Layout Management - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

Comment: Я глянул видео, я пытался делать такое, но не знал о пружина, которые менять расположение, ну хорошо спасибо. Видимо, не так сильно мне надо менять программу